# Bootstrap 4 mobile view: label has too much padding / input fields have too little padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple password field with Bootstrap grid classes:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2" for="passwordField">Password</label>
    <input class="col-sm-3" id="passwordField" type="password" v-model="password"/>
    <button class="col-sm-3">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In mobile view the left space at the label "Password" is bigger than the left space to the input field:
[image]

This is kind of ugly. Can it be done better without extra CSS, or is it a bug (or feature) of Bootstrap?!

See https://jsfiddle.net/0tkco9ws/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to myself: just read the docs.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form

So a better approach would be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="passwordField">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordField"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button class="form-control my-2 my-sm-0">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvnqa58u/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug even not a feature of bootstrap, it's taking padding, so that's why  it is in the same line at laptop view there is no issue when it will go to mobile view not in the same line the padding remains a issue . you can add `p-0` class to the `label`. when you will use it, it won't take no padding.